# Open new images in ImageJ always in the same window programatically (java)

Tags: java, singleton, imagej

I am using imageJ to extend some functionality of a Swing application

I want to open an image with ImageJ using java, but i want to keep the same image window and not a new window per each image opened..

```
ImagePlus imp = IJ.openImage(imageFilepath)  
imp.show()
```

also tried something like that but could not figure it out from the documentation..

```
   ImagePlus imp  
   imp = IJ.openImage(imageFile.absolutePath)  
   if (imp) {  
        imp.setImage(imp)  
   }  
   imp.show()
```

Comment: I dont' know how it works with ImageJ, but u can also use a JFrame with an image in it. The JFrame will not close when u change the image

Comment: Yes, but i dont want to open an image on a JFrame, i want to use the functionality of ImageJ..

Comment: Did you try it?? Show how you tried it

Comment: I just did upstairs..

Comment: of course i tried many others.. typical singleton pattern.. problem is I couldnt infer from the documentation the classes related to the window, or whatever object is used to get that reference and dont create it again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readin the doc you should do something like this:

```
class YourClass {
    ImagePlus imp;

    public void openImage( String imageFilepath ) {
        if ( imp == null {
            imp = IJ.openImage(imageFilepath);  
        }
        else {
           // Reuse
           ImagePlus imp2 = IJ.openImage(imageFilepath);
           imp.setImage(imp2) 
        }
        imp.show();  
    }
}
```